# How can I transmit from a component to another when redirecting in VueJS?

Tags: session, redirect, vue.js, vue-router

I'm currently working on a login form that will redirect the user to the "/admin" once he's connected. However, if he tries to type "/admin" while not logged, he'll be redirected to "/login".

What I would like is to be able to display a message of why he's here (Something like "You must be connected to continue"). I'd also would like to make the same thing when typing "/login" while he's connected (in which case he'll be redirected with a message saying "you're already logged in")

I tried to pass datas in different ways, but somehow, I can't retrieve it, and I'm pretty sure that's because I'm not doing it the right way.

This is the "/admin" vue layout, that makes sure that the user is constantly logged in.

```
beforeCreate () {
    this.$axios.get('/logged_in')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.data) { // either returns true or false
          this.$router.replace({ name: 'login', params: { error: 'not_logged' } })
        }
      })
  }
```

This is the login form, and "how" I tried to retrive the params's content

```
created () {
    this.$axios.get('/logged_in')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          this.$router.replace({ name: 'admin', params: { error: 'already_loggedin' } })
        }
      })
    console.log(this.$router.params)
  }
}

watch: {
  $route (to, from) {
    console.log(to)
    console.log(from)
  }
}
```

Out of 3 `console.logs`, only the first one (`this.$router.params`) actually shows up in the console, with `undefined`.

What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Out of 3 console.logs, only the first one (this.$router.params) actually shows up

That's most likely because your component has been unmounted after route change. That's why watchers don't work anymore.

About the first console.log, if you redirected here from the first component with:

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'login', params: { error: 'not_logged' } })
```

Then I think $route.params should have this param (not $router.params).

Also you can declare props on component and pass them from route definition as described here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Notice:

> When props is set to true, the route.params will be set as the component props.